# Выделение цифры из числа и замена

Tags: java

Дано число n, надо заменить третью цифру на цифру "0".
Ввод:123456
Вывод:120456

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Где возникли затруднения?

Comment: Не понимаю, принцип замены и "вставки" цифры

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Получите строку из числа методом  `String#valueOf(Integer i)`
2. Получите 3 по счёту символ в строке методом `String#charAt(int index)`
3. Замените его на нужный методом `String#replace(String str, String str1)`

```
String n = String.valueOf(123456);
String thirdChar = n.charAt(2).toString();
String result = n.replace(thirdChar, String.valueOf(0);
```

---

Но это не сработает если заменяемое число появляется в т.ч. до 3 позиции в строке.

Вот другой способ:

1. Преобразуем строку, полученную из числа в массив букв методом `String#toCharArray()`.
2. Заменяем букву в массиве в нужной ячейке
3. Преобразуем массив букв обратно в строку через конструктор `String(Char[] charArray)`.

```
String n = String.valueOf(123456);
Char[] array = n.toCharArray();
array[2] = String.valueOf(0);
String result = new String(array);
```